# Else statement is executing when TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am completely new to coding. I am a teacher and trying to design a lesson planner tool using Google Sheets Scripts. The idea is to have a template sheet for the lesson that will copy into a new tab. That part is working fine. However, to delete the lesson I want to make it impossible for someone to accidentally delete the template. It is succeeding in not deleting the template tab if "Delete Lesson" is clicked.

However, it is displaying the alert that you cannot delete the template for the other tabs (but then deleting the tab as it should) This is the [document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJS27kGQni02TmV6PbHQdl4fxYop6VKKZHNRWQaI0yc/edit?usp=sharing).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**I used this code at first:**

```
function DeleteTab1() {  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetname = sheet.getName();


  if(sheetname != "Template")  { 
    spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  }

  else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The template cannot be deleted');
     } 
}
```

**Then I tried this and had the same problem:**

```
function DeleteTab1() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetname = sheet.getName();


  if(sheetname != "Template")  { 
    spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  }

  if(sheetname = "Template") {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The template cannot be deleted');
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second code, bear in mind that on Google Apps Script/JavaScript a single equal sign (`=`) is used to assign a literal or an objecto to a variable, so the syntax of the comparison on  following code line is wrong

```
if(sheetname = "Template") {
```

The correct syntax is

```
if(sheetname === "Template") {
```

Notes:

On Google Apps Script / JavaScript:

- `===` means strict equality comparison
- `==` means abstract equality comparison

Regarding the first code you should put the `else` keyword on the same like as the if closing bracket `}` because that is the right syntax and because the automatic semi-colon insertion,

Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

Answer (score 0):

- you could try like this which will prevent deleting the **Template** sheet:

  ```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
   case "Template":
   break;
   default:
   ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);}}
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured it I just delete the second half (Ui.Alert), it will prevent the Template from being deleted while not having the popup problem. However, I would like if possible to display the alert if they click delete when on the template.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had another function with the same name it was running the other one instead.