# Send email when cell value equals 29

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am having trouble with my google sheets script and I wondered if anyone had any advice for a beginner. I want my script to check a cell value (Sheet1, H2), then send an email if the value = 29. However, at the moment it will send an email whatever value it returns, I don't think my if statement works correctly. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

[image]

```
function CheckExpiry() {
  // Fetch the days till expiry.
  var ExpiryDataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("H2"); 
  var ExpiryData = ExpiryDataRange.getValue();
  // Check expiration
  if(ExpiryData = 29){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'You are recieving this email as harness # is up for inspection soon, current inspection expires in the following number of days: ' + ExpiryData; // Second column
    var subject = 'Your Harness Spreadsheet Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ExpiryData = 29
```

by

```
ExpiryData === 29
```

In JavaScript / Google Apps Script a single `=` means assign to left operand the right operand (in this specific case, `ExpiryData = 29` means assign `29` to `ExperyData`). There are two comparison operators to compare "equality", `==` and `===`, while the first is shorter usually it's harder to understand by begginers, so I suggest you to use the second.

Related

- [Else statement is executing when TRUE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/131486/88163)
- [How do I run multiple onEdit functions in the same spreadsheet in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138939/88163)
- [Can't get If Else statement to run based on value of edited drop-down selection in Google Sheets Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/141124/88163)